# "Unauthentic" vs. "inauthentic"

Tags: differences, adjectives, negation, prefixes, negative-prefixes

Is there really no difference between *inauthentic* and *unauthentic*?

If there is, which is more correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Inauthentic* and *unauthentic* both mean the same thing: ‘not authentic’. Either is acceptable,

but according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unauthentic%2C%20inauthentic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunauthentic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinauthentic%3B%2Cc0)  *inauthentic* is by far the more common term.

[In-  vs Un- prefix](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm) states:

> There is a rule, but it’s only of value to somebody who knows which language the root word came from, so it’s really no help at all for most of us. In general, words take un- when they are of English (Germanic) origin and in- if they come from Latin. (The forms im-, il-, and ir- are variations on in-.)

Comment: That's really helpful. Hadn't thought to use Ngram to check. Thanks a lot! I'll mark as correct when the timer runs out.